# Multiple main storyboards in one Xcode file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am currently working on a mobile app on Xcode (I believe Xcode 11). I have the original main storyboard in tact. However, I ended up duplicating the main storyboard and renaming it something else, then I completed another component on that interface of that storyboard. However, I now want to merge the duplicated storyboard with the original main storyboard without having to make another view controller on the original one but I don’t know how. Help?

Comment: It sounds like the only difference between the two storyboards is that the duplicated has one more view controller. Why not just delete the original storyboard, and rename the duplicated one to `Main.storyboard`?

Comment: You could just copy the scene between the old storyboard and the new one? You'll have to fix any broken segues etc.

Answer (score 0):

What best you can do is store copy duplicated `Storyboard` on desktop . Resolve conflict by considering Main `Storyboard` . Now Copy Controllers you have made on duplicate `Storyboard` from desktop into your `main Storyboard`.

Thats what I prefer to do when multiple developers working on same `Storyboard`.